# WSDL import issue Delphi XE2

Tags: java, delphi, wsdl, delphi-xe2

On my server I previously had method:

```
public boolean isValid(NameMinData[] names){
}
```

So Delphi generated type:

```
Array_Of_NameMinData = array of NameMinData;
```

Later I add a method on my server:

```
public NameMinData[] getValidNames(NameMinData[] names){
}
```

After generation Delphi changed my type name into:

```
getValidNamesResponse = array of NameMinData;
```

This is very annoying because I used this type in a lot of places. Any idea is to how to force Delphi to generate original name?

Comment: Can you show your WSDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I poked around and figured out that you need to check `Map pure collections to wrapper class types`. This resolved my issue.

[image]